# Partialjs - Get model to render in _layout.html

Tags: javascript, html, layout, partial

I have a problem when get model in _layout.html

In default.js, I have model like that

```
exports.install = function(framework) {
    framework.route('/', index);
};
function index(){
    var model = {menu: {url:'/product',name:'Product'}};
    self.view('index', model);
}
```

in index.html, I can get model.menu

```
<ul class="menu_index">
     <!-- I can see model.menu here -->
     <li><a href="{model.menu.url}">{model.menu.name}</a></li>
</ul>
```

but in _layout.htmt, I can't

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu_layout">
        <!-- But I can't see model.menu here -->
    <li><a href="{model.menu.url}">{model.menu.name}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>@{body}</div>
</body>
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the model is for current view, not for the layout. You must use a repository object.

controller:

```
function index() {
   var self = this;
   self.repository.menu = { url:'/product', name: 'Product' };
   self.view('index');
}
```

index:

```
<ul class="menu_index">
     <li><a href="{repository.menu.url}">{repository.menu.name}</a></li>
</ul>
```

layout:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu_layout">
    <li><a href="{repository.menu.url}">{repository.menu.name}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>@{body}</div>
</body>
```

Thanks :-)